# How to change the background image of one category in magento?

Tags: css, magento

I want to change the background of one category page in magento. i did it from css but it is applying for all the pages in magento.  i want to change only one category page background.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from the css file, but you have to be careful what class you use. For each page Magento adds one or more classes to the `body` element. You can use that.
All category pages have the body class `catalog_category_view`. This is useful if you want to change something for all the categories, but there are also category specific classes.
[take this page for example](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/apparel/shoes): It has the classes `categorypath-apparel-shoes category-shoes`. So you can use either `categorypath-apparel-shoes` that is built from the full category path, or `category-shoes` that is generated from the url key of the category.
**[EDIT]**
An other approach would be to include a css file just for that specific category. Magento offers layout handles for each category. Let's say that your category has the id 8. You can add this in your layout file:

```
<CATEGORY_8>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/category8.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_8>
```

now create the file `skin/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/css/category8.css` and add your magic in there. It will only be loaded for your specific category.

Comment: i cant find <CATEGORY_8>. and there isnt {interface}/{theme}folder ,should i create these two folders.i am sorry but i did not get you clear enough.

Comment: @MSohrabZia {interface} and {theme} are just placeholders for your theme name. You can add your css in `skin/frontend/base/default/css` if you want. As for `<CATEGORY_8>` ... it doesn't exist. But if you create it it will be loaded. Just remember to change `8` into your category id.

Answer (score 0):

The body tag of a category page should have a class name that is equal to "category-" + category name of that current page.

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple solution with free extention http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping.html