# Where can i find css code for specific category in magento?

Tags: css, magento

i want to change css for one category. where can i find it and how can i do it for only one category?  e-g i want to change background image of only one category.

Not the whole website.i need to locate css for that category.please help me anyone..ill be very glad

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19291217/2047249

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the background image of one category in magento?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291083/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-one-category-in-magento)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
Go to category and Select the category you want to change.
then open the TAB custom design.

In the field "Custom Layout Update" insert this:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet>css/CSSwithCustomBackground.css</stylesheet>
    <params>media="all"</params>
</action>
```

this loads a diferent CSS in which you can have a different background for the page.

Save, clean caché and that should work.